# updating countdown timers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to build a script for a Penny Auction site like swoopo.com

What framework should I use?
Whats the best way to keep the timers updated without using too much bandwidth?

This all started when I started looking at all the junk thats currently out there.
Most are using PHP and javascript and I feel there is a much better solution.

I have only ever coded in PHP and java and am looking to use this project to learn something new. I have been looking into RoR, would this be suitable for this kind of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be able to do server pushes.
In ruby you can use orbited (http://github.com/collin/orbited-ruby).

Comment: So I would assume in this case you would get the timer information on load. Set it up with Javascript and then update on Push? How accurate would this be? as ever user needs the same time.

Comment: The time should be calculated by javascript on the client maschien. Pushing is a way to lower the bandwidth and let the clients be up to date and also to reset the initial time on the client.

Comment: not sure if you are familiar with penny auctions, Each time a bid is placed the time on the auction increases by 10 seconds (for example).
So in the last 10 seconds of the auction. we may have quite a few people constantly bidding on an item.
Will Push be enough to keep every user updated?

Comment: the advatange of pushing ist that you send date if there is any.
If you do the standart ayax pop your client have to do this periodicaly even if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all webapplication you want in all kind of programmation language.

Ruby on Rails is made to do webapplication. You want made a webapplication. So you can do it with this framework. There are nothing better to say.

Made an application with any language can be slowest than an other even if the language is quicker. It's always depends how you code it.

Ruby On Rails help to maintain easily your code and more readable. It's maybe not the better language in each case. But in each case, it's works and do what you want.